# Map a xml payload to different POJO objects

Tags: data-binding, jaxb

Currently i am developing webservices using CXF framework. This webservices will do my DB operations by making a call to my DAO layer. I know by default CXF is using JAXB for databinding.
For example if i wants to create a new person i am having my webservice like follows.

```
public Response createPerson(CreatePersonRequest request)
{

// Call to hibernate DAO class
personDao.create()
}
```

Here CreatePersonRequest is my DTO class(JAXB annotated) , before i make a call to my DAO class i wants to convert my DTO class object to Hibernate Entity object. I wants to populate my hibernate entity object based on the XML i received from my webservice. But the XML i am receiving here will fit into CreatePersonRequest not to my Person entity object.Because my XML root tag will be  not  other than this my properties for both classes are same. In short i wants to populate Two different type of POJO objects for the same XML payload.Is there anyway to achieve this one using JAXB ? Please help me.

Comment: If I understand your question right it should just work.  What problem are you seeing?  Can you provide additional details?

Comment: Thank you for your reply . I have two classes like PersonRequest and Person. So the root tag name for this two classes is different. The xml payload i am receiving is <PersonRequest> , so i can able to populate the PersonRequest object using JAXB not the Person request , not only this case sometimes i will receive the xml like <UpdatePersonRequest> also , that time also i needs to populate the Person object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use XStream to change the Root tag of the Payload using the XStream alias features after that i can convert to my entity objects.